# Manipulate a list merge based on a index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have this 2 list of lists:

```
list1=[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 3579]]

list2=[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740]]
```

^^ That is just a example, I will have more lists inside but the principle and format will be the same.

I will explain how I would like to format my desired output: when list2[0][1] ==list1[0][1] (in my example 186==186) replace all list2[0] on list1[0] but only keep list1[0][3] (in my example 550), if you don't have a match list2[0][1] ==list1[0][1] (in my example user2 - 282 isn't matched) take that list as it is and modify only index[4] to 0 (will become like this: ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 0])

I will put my desired output so you will understand it better:

```
desiredlist = [['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 0], ['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740]]
```

I would like to have a function that can do that, I started to work on it, and I ended with this:

```
def mergesafirmacheta(safir,macheta):
    combined_list = macheta + safir
    final_dict = {tuple(i[:2]):tuple(i[2:]) for i in combined_list}
    merged_list = [list(k) + list (final_dict[k]) for k in final_dict]
    return merged_list
```

But if I print desiredlist = mergesafirmacheta(list2,list1) I will get:

```
[['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 3579], ['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740]]
```

How I can get to my desired output?I'm using python 3! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have structured data, I would advise you to create class *User* and manipulate with objects.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, nick, id_, months, a, b):
        self.nick = nick
        self.id_ = id_
        self.months = months
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "{self.nick}, {self.id_}, {self.months}, {self.a}, {self.b}".format(**locals())
```

You would have much more readable code.

```
list1 = [
    User('user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555),
    User('user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 3579),
]
list2 = [
    User('user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740),
]

for outdated in list1:
    updateds = [u for u in list2 if outdated.id_ == u.id_]
    if updateds:
        outdated.nick = updateds[0].nick
        outdated.months = updateds[0].months
        outdated.b = updateds[0].b
    else:
        outdated.b = 0

for user in list1:
    print(user)
```

Comment: I started with a list of lists as a data structure and I can't quite get back to objects, I tested anyway your code, but for user2 the last element is 3579 and not 0 like my desired output.

Comment: @TatuBogdan I see now, edited. Well, I won't force you, but after a while, you won't have a clue what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

From the example,I guess that you will benefit from using namedtuples however the solution is based on list comprehension:

```
desiredlist=[list2[0][:3]+[n2,list2[0][4]] if n1==list2[0][1] 
            else [id,n1,dates,n2,0] for id,n1,dates,n2,n3 in list1]
```

Using namedtuples you would have something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Record=namedtuple("Record","Id n1 dates n2 n3")
Example1=Record('user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555)
Example2=Record('user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 3579)
Example3=Record('user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740)
list1=[Example1,Example2]
# Instead of creating a list of 1 element ( list2) I would rather compare it against the namedtuple directly
list2=Example3
# now the merging would look like this
desiredlist=[Record(*list2[:3],n2=i.n2,n3=list2.n3) if i.n1==list2.n1 
        else Record(*i[:4],n3=0) for i in list1]
# now desiredlist would look like:
[Record(Id='user1', n1=186, dates='Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', n2=550, n3=740), Record(Id='user2', n1=282, dates='Mai 2017', n2=3579, n3=0)]
```

if you do not need to append or change the contents of each record it will save you space using namedtuples and it will help you keep the records more readable. Otherwise you will have to use a mutable container, be it dict or list

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need to keep my data in a list of list's, can't work with tuples.

Comment: then the first part of the answer would probably fit your needs

Comment: Oh, I missed that sorry, testing right now, will come back and accept the answer if it works!

Comment: Ok, that works just for my example, but if you extend with more lists the rules won't apply anymore: for example: list1=[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 3579], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 10]] and list2=[['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 100, 1000],['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740]] if I test it will output a total different list from my computation rules.

Comment: The order of lists will be random, won't be user1,user2,user3, more likely user2,user3,user1.

Comment: Then I think you need to re explain your question, since in the question you don't explain which behavior you whant in list 2. Are both lists the same size? should they be looped in parallel (list1[0][1]==list2[0][1],list[1][1] == list2[1][1]...etc) ? Please understand that we can only answer according to the information in the question

Comment: I posted above that I can have more lists and yes, they can be in a random order but with the same format.