# List comprehension to loop over 2 lists of lists and change data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list comprehension function:

```
def mergesafirmacheta(list1,list2):
    desiredlist = [list2[0][:3] + [n2, list2[0][4]] if n1 == list2[0][1]
                   else [id, n1, dates, n2, 0] for id, n1, dates, n2, n3 in list1]
    return desiredlist
```

And my list1 and list2 looks like this:

```
list1=[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], 
       ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 3579], 
       ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 10]]

list2=[['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 100, 1000],
      ['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740]]
```

Where I `if n1 == list2[0][1]`I would like to loop over all lists not just the first one at index[1] position in list2, cause right now I would only get to: `['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 100, 1000]` compare the 282 in my if, but I will never get to 186 in my second list. How I can loop over all of them? (could be that in list2 will have more lists).

Later Edit:

Desired output:

```
[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 740], 
['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 3579, 1000],
['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulate a list merge based on a index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339842/manipulate-a-list-merge-based-on-a-index)

Comment: This is different because I asked about another subject compared to that topic.

Comment: I made the edit.

Comment: Does it have to be a list comprehension? The purpose of those is to make code clear and readable whereas implementing what you want with a comprehension would achieve the opposite..

Comment: Not necessary list comprehension.

Comment: What is your algorithm to get that output? On what basis are you expecting to get the desired output from given two lists? You need to elaborate your question and the way you want to get answer. @TatuBogdan

Answer (score 0):

Add one more loop at begging and change the variables like this:-

```
def mergesafirmacheta(list1,list2):
    desiredlist = [list_2[:3] + [n2, list_2[4]] if n1 == list_2[1]
               else [id, n1, dates, n2, 0] for list_2 in list2 for id, n1, dates, n2, n3 in list1]
    return desiredlist
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Almost, check my desired output, using your adjustments it will output twice for each user: [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 0], ['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740], ['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 3579, 1000], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 0], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0]]

Comment: I changed the code. But your output seems to be according to ' if we were iterating over first list using first list of second list'. Btw, You should really change the code coz it is get unreadable and difficult to define...

Comment: After you changes I will get this: [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 0], ['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 3579, 1000], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0], ['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 0], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0]]  as output, the last 3 list are matching my desired output, the first 3 are wrong. Somewhere it loops twice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
list1=[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 3579, 3579], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 10]]
list2=[['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 100, 1000],['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Apr 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740]]

desiredlist = []
for id, n1, dates, n2, n3 in list1:
    counter = 0
    for list_2 in list2:
        if n1 == list_2[1]:
               desiredlist.append(list_2[:3] + [n2, list_2[4]])
        else:
               counter += 1
               if counter == len(list2):
                   desiredlist.append([id, n1, dates, n2, 0])

print(desiredlist)
```

You want to go to else condition only when NO MATCH found for n1 in list1 for all elements of list2.